# C++ premake5 projects can't "open documents"

Tags: visual-studio, premake

```
I'm converting my C++ solution to using premake5.
```

One issue I've found is that I can no longer open included files in visual studio.

Take this example:

```
#pragma once
#include <util/precompiled.h>
#include <events/EventListener.h>
```

In my current projects I can right click on either included file, and navigate to it.

In the premake5 generated projects, it says it cannot find the source file.

When compiling it is able to find these files, but somehow there is a disconnect with the IDE, so the includes end up with red squiggles.

Frankly this sucks.

Any idea what is is required to inform the IDE how to find these files?

Thanks

PS one difference is that with my manual .vcxproj, they are in the same directory as the .cpp files. 
While with premake I'm placing the .vcxproj out of tree. Mabye this is related??

This leads to red squiggles everywhere:( 
NOTE: it compiles, just an intellisense/IDE issue

[image]

Comment: Did you correctly set your include directories ? (includedirs is the Premake5 command if I remember correctly)

Comment: Changes are your include directories are set incorrectly in the script; they should be specified relative to the project script itself. If you need more help, share the file system layout of your project and a *simple* project script that demonstrates the problem.